# How to use Autocompletetext view in Dialog window in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-2.2-froyo

In My application I want show the autocompletetext view in Dialog window , If run my  application I can not show the dialog window from MainActivity. can any one help me.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private static Context context;

    Button okButton; 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
        final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); 
       MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
       Button search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
       search.setOnClickListener(showSearch);
         }

    private OnClickListener showSearch = new OnClickListener()
      {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {      
               CityListDialog obj=new CityListDialog(context, COUNTRIES);
        }
          };

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MainActivity.context;
    }

    static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { 
          "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", 
          "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
          "Argentina","Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
          "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium" 
        }; 
}
```

### CityListDialog.java

```
public class CityListDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

private ListView list;
private EditText filterText = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
private static final String TAG = "CityList";

public CityListDialog(Context context, String[] cityList) {
    super(context);

    setContentView(R.layout.citylistview);
    this.setTitle("Select City");
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditBox);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cityList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Selected Item is = "+list.getItemAtPosition(position));
                }
    });
}
public void onClick(View v) {
}
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
};
@Override
public void onStop(){
    filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}
}
```

[image: For example this image for show the autocompletetext in dialog window]

Comment: have you used dialog.show() ?

Comment: I dont know where to use show()

Comment: In the showSearch onclick listener use obj.show();

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3j3vcn91x01311/Screenshot%202015-01-05%2017.33.36.png?dl=0 I got error in Dialog.show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see **`.show();`**

So to fix I think that you must do

```
CityListDialog obj=new CityListDialog(context, COUNTRIES);
obj.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static Context context;

   Button okButton; 

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
       final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); 
     context = this.getApplicationContext();
      Button search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
      search.setOnClickListener(showSearch);
        }

   private OnClickListener showSearch = new OnClickListener()
     {

       public void onClick(View v)
       {      
              showDialogList();
       }


         };

   public static Context getAppContext() {
       return MainActivity.context;
   }

   static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { 
         "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", 
         "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
         "Argentina","Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
         "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium" 
       }; 


   private void showDialogList() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.citylistview,null);

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.List);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        AutoCompleteTextView  filterText = (AutoCompleteTextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.EditBox);
        filterText.setAdapter(adapter);
        dialog.setContentView(view);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

replace your citylistview.xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/EditBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
 </AutoCompleteTextView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/List"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```